# VBA: If Then Else Trouble with Attempted DCF Macro

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a macro to project a DCF for up to five years, allowing for different projected cash flows for each period. I also want the user to have the option to run the macro for fewer years. I believe the if then else statements are tripping up the code, but I am honestly very lost. I am looking for a way to use If/Then with GoTo to run different programs depending on the number of periods.

Thanks for helping a novice. Here is my (nonworking) code:

```
 Sub DCFFiveYears()

Dim x As Double, CF1 As Double, CF2 As Double, CF3 As Double, CF4 As Double, CF5 As Double, DR As Double, Periods As Integer



DR = InputBox("Enter the discount rate as a decimal. ", "Discount Rate")



If Periods = 1 Then GoTo OnePeriod

ElseIf Periods = 2 Then GoTo TwoPeriod

ElseIf Periods = 3 Then GoTo ThreePeriod

ElseIf Periods = 4 Then GoTo FourPeriod

ElseIf Periods = 5 Then GoTo FivePeriod

End If

Periods = InputBox("Enter the number of periods.", "Periods")






OnePeriod:
  CF1 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-1 cash flow", "Cash Flow")

  Dim x As Double
  x = CF1 / (1# + DR)

Range("A1") = x
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
  Exit Sub

TwoPeriod:

    CF1 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-1 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF2 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-2 cash flow", "Cash Flow")

  Dim x As Double
  x = (CF1 / (1# + DR) ^ 1) + (CF2 / (1# + DR) ^ 2)

Range("A1") = x
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
  Exit Sub


ThreePeriod:

    CF1 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-1 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF2 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-2 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF3 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-3 cash flow", "Cash Flow")

 Dim x As Double
  x = (CF1 / (1# + DR) ^ 1) + (CF2 / (1# + DR) ^ 2) + (CF3 / (1# + DR) ^ 3)

Range("A1") = x
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
  Exit Sub

FourPeriod:


    CF1 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-1 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF2 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-2 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF3 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-3 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF4 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-4 cash flow", "Cash Flow")



 Dim x As Double
  x = (CF1 / (1# + DR) ^ 1) + (CF2 / (1# + DR) ^ 2) + (CF3 / (1# + DR) ^ 3) + (CF4 / (1# + DR) ^ 4)

Range("A1") = x
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
  Exit Sub


FivePeriod:

    CF1 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-1 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF2 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-2 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF3 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-3 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF4 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-4 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF5 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-5 cash flow", "Cash Flow")


 Dim x As Double
  x = (CF1 / (1# + DR) ^ 1) + (CF2 / (1# + DR) ^ 2) + (CF3 / (1# + DR) ^ 3) + (CF4 / (1# + DR) ^ 4) + (CF5 / (1# + DR) ^ 5)


Range("A1") = x
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
  Exit Sub



ErrorMessage:

MsgBox "Invalid input. Code has terminated.", , "Error!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Work with Select Case Statement - https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures#t=201704062312125690151

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with what 0m3r mentions, makes more sense to organize what you have going on here into a case statement and I'd add that you could fit most of your case procedures into their own sub procedures.  I'd also submit that your "periods" input box in the code above appears beyond the scope of the If statements so you're not gonna jump back up and you're always gonna run oneperiod into exit sub.

you could try something like this:

```
Dim DR as double

Sub DCFFiveYears()

Dim x As Double, CF1 As Double, CF2 As Double, CF3 As Double, CF4 As Double, CF5 As Double,Periods As Integer

DR = InputBox("Enter the discount rate as a decimal. ", "Discount Rate")
Periods = InputBox("Enter the number of periods", "Periods")
Select Case Periods
    Case 1
        OnePeriod
    Case 2
        TwoPeriod
    Case 3
        ThreePeriod
    Case 4
        FourPeriod
    Case 5
        FivePeriod
End Select



End Sub
Sub OnePeriod()
  CF1 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-1 cash flow", "Cash Flow")

  Dim x As Double
  x = CF1 / (1# + DR)

Range("A1") = x
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
End Sub

Sub TwoPeriod()

    CF1 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-1 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF2 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-2 cash flow", "Cash Flow")

  Dim x As Double
  x = (CF1 / (1# + DR) ^ 1) + (CF2 / (1# + DR) ^ 2)

Range("A1") = x
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
End Sub


Sub ThreePeriod()

    CF1 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-1 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF2 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-2 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF3 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-3 cash flow", "Cash Flow")

 Dim x As Double
  x = (CF1 / (1# + DR) ^ 1) + (CF2 / (1# + DR) ^ 2) + (CF3 / (1# + DR) ^ 3)

Range("A1") = x
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
End Sub

Sub FourPeriod()
    CF1 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-1 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF2 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-2 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF3 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-3 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF4 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-4 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
 Dim x As Double
  x = (CF1 / (1# + DR) ^ 1) + (CF2 / (1# + DR) ^ 2) + (CF3 / (1# + DR) ^ 3) + (CF4 / (1# + DR) ^ 4)

Range("A1") = x
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
End Sub


Sub FivePeriod()

    CF1 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-1 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF2 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-2 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF3 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-3 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF4 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-4 cash flow", "Cash Flow")
    CF5 = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-5 cash flow", "Cash Flow")


 Dim x As Double
  x = (CF1 / (1# + DR) ^ 1) + (CF2 / (1# + DR) ^ 2) + (CF3 / (1# + DR) ^ 3) + (CF4 / (1# + DR) ^ 4) + (CF5 / (1# + DR) ^ 5)


Range("A1") = x
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
End Sub



ErrorMessage:

MsgBox "Invalid input. Code has terminated.", , "Error!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a loop:

```
Sub DCFFiveYears()

    Dim x As Double
    Dim DR As Double
    Dim Periods As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim CF As Double

    Periods = InputBox("Enter the number of periods.", "Periods")
    DR = InputBox("Enter the discount rate as a decimal. ", "Discount Rate")

    x = 0
    For p = 1 To Periods
        CF = InputBox("Please enter the predicted YEAR-" & p & " cash flow", "Cash Flow")

        x = x + CF / (1# + DR) ^ p
    Next
    With Range("A1")
        .Value = x
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        .Style = "Currency"
    End With
End Sub
```